# Transforming an array from key to value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array returned by a match(). So elements are ordered this way:

`0 => "value1"
 1 => "value2"
 ...`

What I would like to do is to create a new array indexed by keys that are values of the first array, so it would look this way :

`value1 => "newValue1"
 value2 => "newValue2"
 ...`

How to do that in javascript ? (I'm not very advanced in javascript, sorry if it looks simple to you)

Comment: what will be the values of keys ?

Comment: I've put value1 as an example, it is not meant to be replaced by an actual value. So the new array keys name will be value1, value2, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about this method https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/match.

First thing to know, there is no "indexed array" in Javascript, only an Object in the best of the case.

So let's say you want to go from this (indexes are implicit)

```
["value1", "value2", ...]
```

to this

```
{
    "value1": "newValue1",
    "value2": "newValue2",
    [...]
},
```

A simple forEach will do the job:

```
var myArray = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];
var result = {};

myArray.forEach(function(item){
    result[item] = "new"+item;    
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle that will perform what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/0qqq6mm1/

Comment: Thanks, yes I understood I had to use an object for that but didn't figure out how to set the indexes properly. Thanks a lot.
In term of efficiency of the code, which solution do you think will be better, yours or the one with .reduce() ?

Comment: For such a simple task, I do not think you will notice any difference in terms of efficiency, except with thousands / millions of entries.

If you want a simple comparison, you can have a look at this JSPerf : http://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-reduce-vs-for-loop.

It seems your best bet is the "optimized for loop".
However, some other criteria might be at stake. 

Also, you can have a look at this SO discussion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546450/for-array-is-it-more-efficient-to-use-map-reduce-instead-of-foreach-in

Comment: thanks! jsperf is very interesting for me :) I will basically process 200 data, and it will execute on computers that can be quite old, but the users will require quick results (it is for lawyers so time is money :) ).
Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use [*Array.reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as bellow.

```
var arr1 = ["val1","val2","val3"];

var obj = arr1.reduce(function(prev,next,index){
    prev[next] = "newValue"+(index+1);
    return prev;
},{});
```

If you will print the contents of `obj` it will look like bellow

```
Object {val1: "newValue1", val2: "newValue2", val3: "newValue3"}
```