# Joining multiple objects by a key in javascript

Tags: javascript

Let say I have an array of objects like this:

```
data = [
    {
        set: "a",
        values: [
            {time: 1, value: 10},
            {time: 2, value: 13},
            {time: 3, value: 12}
        ]
    },
    {
        set: "b",
        values: [
            {time: 1, value: 22},
            {time: 2, value: 24},
            {time: 3, value: 27}
        ]
    },
    {
        set: "c",
        values: [
            {time: 1, value: 34},
            {time: 2, value: 38},
            {time: 3, value: 18}
        ]
    },
    {
        set: "d",
        values: [
            {time: 1, value: 24},
            {time: 2, value: 19},
            {time: 3, value: 22}
        ]
    }
]
```

and I want to join the objects by time like this:

```
data = [
    {time: 1, set_a: 10, set_b: 22, set_c: 34, set_d: 24},
    {time: 2, set_a: 13, set_b: 24, set_c: 38, set_d: 19},
    {time: 3, set_a: 12, set_b: 27, set_c: 18, set_d: 22}
]
```

On way I could do this would be to putll the unique time keys and then loop throuh each set and create a new object with thsoe values. But is this the most efficient way of doing it? Or is there a function that does somethign similar?

Comment: you should try first...then ask when you run into issues. This isn't a *"how to"* tutorial site or a free code writing service. The objective here is to help you with **your code** when it doesn't perform as expected. It sounds like you have a pretty good idea on how to start...and jumped the gun asking us

Comment: @charlietfl I disagree - OP provides an abstract approach and asks if there are more efficient ways to solve the stated problem. Code is not always required.

Comment: @le_m disagree all you want, but the norm is for OP to at least show attempts and/or research efforts as outlined in [help]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to pull your sleeves up and loop your objects :) one way or another :(

Comment: _"On way I could do this would be to putll the unique time keys and then loop throuh each set and create a new object with thsoe values. But is this the most efficient way of doing it?"_ What do you mean by "efficient"? Without further clarity as to definition of "efficient", yes. As no code or benchmark of code appears at Question to compare.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [map reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

Example:

```
// data = { ... }

var result = data.map(function (item) {
  var tmp = {};
  for (var i in item.values) {
    tmp[item.values[i].time] = { ['set_' + item.set]: item.values[i].value };
  }
  return tmp;
}).reduce(function (a, b) {
  for (i in a) {
    Object.assign(a[i], b[i])
  }
  return a;
});
```

The efficiency for the method has been discussed here:

[For Array, is it more efficient to use map() & reduce() instead of forEach() in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546450/for-array-is-it-more-efficient-to-use-map-reduce-instead-of-foreach-in)

Answer (score 0):

This is a traversal problem, to output your result, you must traverse through every item. However, the sets are independent from one another, one cant' just deduce the latter set value from a previous computation. The solution can't be 
optimized without traversing the tree. Here is a simple O(m*n) time solution, where m is the number of times and n is the number of sets (a, b, c...)

```js
const data = [
    {
        set: "a",
        values: [
            {time: 1, value: 10},
            {time: 2, value: 13},
            {time: 3, value: 12}
        ]
    },
    {
        set: "b",
        values: [
            {time: 1, value: 22},
            {time: 2, value: 24},
            {time: 3, value: 27}
        ]
    },
    {
        set: "c",
        values: [
            {time: 1, value: 34},
            {time: 2, value: 38},
            {time: 3, value: 18}
        ]
    },
    {
        set: "d",
        values: [
            {time: 1, value: 24},
            {time: 2, value: 19},
            {time: 3, value: 22}
        ]
    }
];

function processData(data) {
  if (data.length === 0 || data[0].values.length === 0) 
    return [];
  const result = [];
  const times = data[0].values.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    const item = {};
    item.time = data[0].values[i].time;
    data.forEach(x => item["set_" + x.set] = x.values[i].value);
    result.push(item);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(processData(data));
```